# Is IIS redirecting to match url casing?

Tags: ios, redirect, iis, case-sensitive

I have a WebAPI, which is a part of a bigger WebForms app, deployed on IIS 10 under the `https://domain/SimpleApp`.

I have noticed that when calling an API endpoint using `https://domain/simpleapp/api/endpoint` I'm getting redirected (status code 302) to `https://domain/SimpleApp/api/endpoint`.

I didn't set any url-rewrite rules.

It is causing some errors when consuming the API on iOS app - some endpoints are secured, and when redirecting, the "Authorization" header is dropped (default behavior on Apple platform). For the record: the redirect occurs for both, secured and non-secured endpoints.

Is it some default IIS configuration?  Can it be changed, so it will not redirect the request (or is it easier to handle this issue on the iOS app)?

Comment: You can use FRT to trace such 30x responses https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis Then from where they come should be clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found what was the issue. It is nicely described in this post: [Beware WIF Session Authentication Module (SAM) redirects and WebAPI services in the same application](https://brockallen.com/2013/02/08/beware-wif-session-authentication-module-sam-redirects-and-webapi-services-in-the-same-application/)